# Difference between importing java.util.* and java.util.concurrent.*

Tags: java

What is the basic difference between `import java.util.*;` and `import java.util.concurrent.*;`?

When we say `java.util.*` the concurrent package in util should also get imported. Then why specify it separately?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's important to research before asking, which I think is why the question has been downvoted ("lacks research effort" is one of the reasons shown by the downvote button's tooltip).

Answer (score 3):

> When we say java.util.* the concurrent package in util should also get imported.

No, `import java.util.*` just imports the classes in `java.util`, not packages under it.

The [Java packages tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**java.util.** statement will only import class under java.util package and will not import classes under any sub-packages.  To import classes under **java.util.concurrent**, you need to add import statement java.util.concurrent.